# Kafka producer failover mechanism and validation of data being pushed to topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have written a code to push data to kafka topic on daily basis, but there are few issue which i am not sure this code will be able to handle. my responsibility is to push complete data from a live table which holds 1 day data(refreshed every day morning)

my code will query "select * from mytable" and push it one by one to kafka topic as before pushing i need to validate/alter each row and push to topic.

**below is my producer send code.**

```
    Properties configProperties = new Properties();
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, sBOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG);
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        configProperties.put("acks", "all");
        configProperties.put("retries", 0);
        configProperties.put("batch.size", 15000);
        configProperties.put("linger.ms", 1);
        configProperties.put("buffer.memory", 30000000);
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configProperties);
        System.out.println("Starting Kafka producer job  " + new Date());
        producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(eventName, jsonRec.toString()), new Callback() {
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                if (e != null) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now, i am not sure how to push data back again into topic in case of failure. Since i have selected all the records from table and few of it got failed and i do not know which all.

**Below is what i want to address**

1. how can process only those records which are not pushed to avoid duplicate  record being push(avoid redundancy).
2. how to validate the records pushed are exactly same as in table. i mean the data integrity. like size of data and count of records been pushed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `configProperties.put("enable.idempotence", true);` - it will try to retry failed messages but make sure there will be just one of each record saved in kafka. Note that it implies that `retries>0` `acks=all` and `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` >=0. For details check https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/.

For 2nd question - if you mean that you need to save all records or none then you have to use kafka transactions, which brings a lot more questions, I would recommend reading https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/

Comment: so for 1st point, will it query the table again and try to push the data which is not already pushed?   
i will go through the document and get back.. thanks for your reply :)

Comment: no it won' query db again. Kafka producer does not know anything about your db so if you call producer.send 2nd time anywhere for same record then you will get duplicates. `retries` works internally in kafka code, so it will know it should try to send same record again and again because for example it did not get acks from kafka broker.